# memory allocation for pointers inside struct

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

Recently this question was asked on stack overflow , but I have different doubt regarding memory allocation.

In this line `Graph *G=malloc(sizeof(*G))` here memory allocation is for pointer to `Graph` and  and if you want to say that memory allocation for other member of struct  is not happening inside any struct then how we are able to access them using `G->var`, since we are allocating memory for only `(*G)` which may be equal to some int value?

If you say:

> It is allocating a Graph structure and assigning G to the address of that structure

than `Graph *g = malloc( sizeof( Graph ) );` will also do the same.

```
struct Edge {
    int vertex;
    int weight;
    Edge *next;
};

struct Graph {
    int v;
    Edge **edge;
    int *dist;
    int *path;
};

Graph *graph_new(int v)
{
    Graph *G = malloc(sizeof(*G));

    G->v = v;
    G->edge = calloc(v, sizeof(*G->edge));
    G->dist = calloc(v, sizeof(*G->dist));
    G->path = calloc(v, sizeof(*G->path));

    return G;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Without the first `malloc`, you can't even access `G -> anything`. It creates the variables inside the `struct`. Without that, `G` is just a pointer pointing to nowhere.

Comment: `Edge *next;` Edge is not a defined type. In C, this should be a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

> ...how we are able to access them using G->var...

It seems you don't understand clearly what a pointer is. A pointer is a simple variable you can read and write as any other. But you can do one more operation on a pointer: dereference it (using * or ->). In order to do this particular operation, the value of the pointer must be valid: a pointer contains an address and, if that address is not valid, an error happens. Think at a pointer as an envelope, written or not. You can read what is written ON the envelope; you can also wipe and write on it. But when you read the address written on the envelope, you want that address exists, otherwise you could go around searching an address which does not exist, and get angry.

The particular value of a pointer can be thought similar to that of an integer. You can take any integer and perform calculations with it but, if you want to *divide* for it, your integer must be different from 0, otherwise an error happens. So is a pointer: you can read it and write it with any value but, if you want to *use* its value as what should normally be, i.e. an address in memory, that value must point to a suitable address. malloc() and calloc() return values which are valid and suitable to be assigned to a pointer, and can be safely used (in normal circustances) when you try to dereference the pointer.

EDIT after comments below.
One normally thinks that, if a program is not guaranteed to behave correctly, it is an error. For the program to always behave correctly, many precautions must be taken. Two of these are 1) Don't use unknown values, and 2) Don't dereference invalid pointers. Errors can be divided finely further, by nomenclature, style, or the effect they produce or can produce. Undefined behavior is the name given by the C language specification to indicate that the compiler (or the target machine) can do whatever they want, because the specification does not mandate anything precise about. Of course, nobody wants "undefined behavior", so making it happen is just an error. And back to dereferencing wrong pointers, the specification says it invokes undefined behavior. Precisely, depending on the target machine and OS, one or more of the following can happen: 1) nothing, apart from reading unknown values; 2) nothing, apart from writing to unknown memory zones; 3) segment faults or other traps/exceptions and so on; 4) CPU overheating, maybe explosion, or other unspecified things.

Now we take a step ahead. If your pointer variable is not a "normal", global variable, but instead resides in dynamic - non allocated - memory, your variable does not exist yet. It is a concept, not a real variable. So, first you create that variable; then you can use it as said before.

In your example, "Struct Graph" is a declaration of a bunch of variables which do not exist until you allocate them. Once you do it, via "Graph *G = malloc(sizeof(*G));", they come to life; but this does not mean they have valid values. In fact, just below creating the struct, in you code fragment, they are accessed. The only legal access to them, in this moment, is to assign them some value. As said before, they could also be read - they actually exist, but their value could (well, IS) illegal.

If the values in the Struct Graph, just created, were simple integers instead of pointers, the matter would be the same: the variables exist, but their content is unknown and hence invalid. Note that you could allocate a Struct Graph using calloc(): in this case the value of the variables inside would not be unknown but, for a pointer, still would be invalid to be dereferenced - like an integer known to be zero and hence invalid to be used as a divisor. But the variables ARE there, ready to be tested against 0 (in case of an integer), or against NULL (or 0) in the case of pointers, or ready to be written with meaningful values.

Hope I've been clear enough to help.

Comment: If you dereference an invalid pointer, an error does not happen -- undefined behavior happens.  That might be an error or might be some subtle corruption of your program that is not immediately apparent.

Comment: @ChrisDodd this raises the question whether UB can be considered an error... For me, everything unwanted is an error, be because the machine or the programmer. Unless you cite a case where UB is exactly desired... I think there are situations where pedantic distinctions are not appropriate.

Comment: "...if that address is not valid, an error happens." -- This is misleading. It is an error (on the part of the programmer) to dereference an invalid pointer, yet the result of dereferencing an invalid pointer is not "an error", but undefined behavior. Many would read what you wrote and think that a runtime error, e.g. a segfault and crash, must follow from an invalid dereference. That might happen, but anything else could happen too. It isn't pedantic to be careful with wording to avoid common misinterpretations.

Comment: @DavidBowling I edited the answer to include your thought. But nobody should think that a crash always comes from an invalid dereference. I didn't say so. Moreover this segfault/crash thing has nothing to do with errors vs undefined behavior, they are different discussions. In my answer I used initially simplified words because it seemed to me that the OP would benefit. "Undefined behavior" doesn't sound clear like "error" to someone that does not understand pointers.

Comment: @linuxfan: UB is *much worse* than an error, as it might appear to work and fail catastophically somewhere down the line -- to say its "just an error" is misleading and understates the importance.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I think that "an error" can do exactly the same thing. Please do not think as an error as something that shows up immediately, I didn't say so; the same for page fault - I didn't write that a page fault implies a badly dereferenced pointer, but someone says so.

Answer (score 0):

`Graph *G=malloc(sizeof(G))` != `Graph *G=malloc(sizeof(*G))`

G is a **pointer** to Graph hence `sizeof(G)` in the first case allocate memory for `Graph *`.

While `sizeof(*G)` in the second case allocates enough memory **for what G points to**, which in this case is `Graph`.

How you choose to allocate memory is entirely up to you and depends on what you intend to do.

Secondly, If you have fields that are pointers in a struct as in `struct Graph`, those will remain unallocated, any attempt to access them will result in an error until you properly allocate memory for them or point them to valid memory locations.